# NULL to zero with ISNULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT name, SUM(growth) AS sum_buy_price, SUM(recovery) AS sum_msrp, SUM(growth)+SUM(recovery) AS total 
FROM orders 
WHERE id = ? 
GROUP BY name
```

My data is coming from a CSV file that I have no control over and either 'growth' or 'recovery' can be NULL in the data, but not at the same time. I need to use ISNULL to convert the possible NULL values to zero in order for the SUM to work correctly, but I'm unsure of how/where to add the ISNULL since the SELECT is indexing another record (name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISNULL returns whether the argument passed is null (i.e., it is analogous to true or false). I suppose, what you need is IFNULL:

```
SELECT
  name,
  SUM(IFNULL(growth, 0))                         AS sum_buy_price,
  SUM(IFNULL(recovery, 0))                       AS sum_msrp,
  SUM(IFNULL(growth, 0))+SUM(IFNULL(recovery,0)) AS total
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  id = ?
GROUP BY
  name
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SUM()` function ignores `NULL` values, so you don't need to change a `NULL` to a `0` in order for it to work properly.

If however, all values that you're aggregating are `NULL` and you want to return a `0` instead of `NULL` you can use `IFNULL()` or the more common `COALESCE()` to show `0` as the sum instead of `NULL`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(growth),0)
```

`ISNULL()` is a valid SQL Server function, `IFNULL()` is the equivalent in MySQL, but all major databases make use of `COALESCE()` which returns the first non-NULL value in a set, ie:  `COALESCE(NULL,NULL,5)` would return `5`.

Comment: will it ignore the entire row that the null is in? so if you do a count(*)| sum(total) and one total value is null, will the count still be incremented?

Comment: It only ignores the `NULL` value for that given column, not the row.  Here's a simple demo:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dbc5b/2/0
Updated demo to show difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(col1)`.

Comment: so count would still increment, but sum(total) would not. thanks

Comment: Exactly, likewise if you didn't want to count the `NULL` rows you could use `COUNT(growth)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT name, SUM(ISNULL(growth, 0)) AS sum_buy_price, 
SUM(ISNULL(recovery, 0)) AS sum_msrp, 
SUM(ISNULL(growth, 0))+SUM(ISNULL(recovery,0)) AS total 
FROM orders 
WHERE id = ? 
GROUP BY name
```